# How to create duplicate nodes in many clusters in graphviz?

Tags: graphviz, dot

I am creating a dot graph with 3 clusters in which 2 clusters have 2 to 3 same nodes. Even though there are same nodes i want them to be repeated in the both the clusters. How should i force the nodes so that they can be repeated/duplicated in clusters?
For visualisation i have attached a picture created from lucid app. As shown here i want to have 2 nodes with same name "node a" in 2 clusters. Please help me to create one. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Nodes must have unique names, but they can have identical labels.

Comment: Okay! Thanks for your response!  So i cant use the same name for nodes in clusters.

Comment: Correct.  Each unique node within a graph must have a unique name - they are "global".  Names however can be duplicated.

Answer (score 1):

To illustrate what's already been said in the comments - node identifiers have to be unique, but labels can be the same:

```
digraph G {
  subgraph cluster_john {
      node_1 [label="Malkovich"]
      node_2 [label="Malkovich"]
      node_1 -> node_2
  }

  subgraph cluster_malkovich {
      node_3 [label="Malkovich"]
      node_4 [label="Malkovich"]
      node_3 -> node_4
  }
}
```

[image: Malkovich graph]